# Correct settings for pfSense and TinyDNS

Tags: domain-name-system, pfsense, tinydns

My TinyDNS install on pfSense is only able to resolve local host names. Any external domains, come back as blank. The strange thing, is that they resolve correctly when SSH'd to the pfSense box. I also want to get the TinyDNS exposed on both LAN and WAN sides. Right now it is just working on LAN side.

Can someone provide the correct pfSense settings for TinyDNS?

Comment: They come back as blank means what exactly? When connected whith a client computer to the PF sense box you cannot resolve external DNS and recieve a warning to that effect in your browser? Or the page loads, says "done" and is literally a blank white page? Have you checked your client computer has the proper DNS settings from the router?

Comment: DNS forwarders are not working, Have you tired google DNS.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking a [content DNS server](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-server-roles.html#Content) to do a resolving [proxy DNS server](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-server-roles.html#Proxy)'s job.  Read the documentation, starting with basics like [the blurb](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/blurb/overview.html), and use the correct server software for the correct task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I've read the TinyDNS package was never actually finished. Also djbDNS is comprised of two parts, TinyDNS and DNSCache. Unfortunately there is no pfSense package for DNSCache.

Unfortunately I've only ever got it to work as you hoped as result of crazy misconfiguration that wasn't too stable (had both pfSense DNS forwarder and TinyDNS answering on the same interface - would work until a reboot)

pfSense already has a built in caching DNS server that allows you to create your own A records.

For a situation where I had to use TinyDNS (to serve some SRV records), I had two pfSense boxes, if my memory serves me correctly, I had one set up as a normal router, but on this, under the DNS server settings, I set an override for a particular domain to point to the other box which was running TinyDNS.

http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=7812.0